# Laravel fullcalendar- How to display the event specifically on the current user?

Tags: php, laravel, fullcalendar

I had developed a system that use maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar.It works and i had no problem to display the calendar with the events.However, there is the problem that the calendar show all events include from different users.Can someone help me to solve this?

**Controller**
    //show the events in the calendar

```
    $events = Schedule::get();
    $events->user()->id;
        $event_list = [];
        foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
            $event_list[] = Calendar::event(
                $event->event_name,
                false,
                new \DateTime($event->start_date),
                new \DateTime($event->end_date),
                null,
                // Add color and link on event
                [
                   'color' => '#05B06C',
                    //'url' => 'http://full-calendar.io',

                ]);
        }

    //Display Fullcalendar

        $calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list)
                            ->setOptions([ //set fullcalendar options
                            'firstDay'=> 1,
                             'editable'=> true,
                             'navLinks'=> true,
                             'selectable'  => true,
                             'durationeditable' => true,

                            ]);

       return view('front.teacher.schedule.index', compact('calendar_details','events') );

}
```

**Model**

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Schedule extends Model
{
     protected $fillable=[
        'event_name','start_date','end_date'
    ];
}

**View**

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' =>'schedule:addEvents','method'=>'POST','files'=>'true'))!!}
            <div class ="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    @if(Session::has('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">{{Session::get('success')}}</div>
                    @elseif (Session::has('warning'))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{Session::get('warning')}}</div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('event_name','Name:') !!}
                            <div class="">
                            {!! Form::text('event_name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                            {!! $errors->first('event_name','<p class="alert alert-danger">:message</p>') !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-sm-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('start_date','Start Date:')!!}
                            <div class="">

                            {!! Form::input('datetime-local','start_date',\Carbon\Carbon::now(),['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                      {!! $errors->first('start_date', '<p class="alert alert-danger">:message</p>') !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            {!!Form::label('end_date','End Date:')!!}
                                <div class="">

                                {!! Form::input('datetime-local','end_date',null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                      {!! $errors->first('end_date', '<p class="alert alert-danger">:message</p>') !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 cold-md-1 text-center">&nbsp;<br/>
                            {!! Form::submit('Add Event',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {!!Form::close() !!}
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">My Event Details</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        {!! $calendar_details->calendar() !!}


                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
              </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection
     @section('script')

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/2.2.7/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>

 {!! $calendar_details->script() !!}
```

**Schedule Table**

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuFGP.png)

Comment: `$events = Schedule::get();` I guess you have to put a WHERE clause in there to specify which user ID you want to restrict it to. I don't know Laravel, so I don't know the exact syntax - but I bet you could look it up. Also I don't know how you are storing which user is logged in currently (maybe in the session perhaps?) so you have to find that out too. This is more of a Laravel/Database question, it doesn't have much to do with fullCalendar I don't think - fullCalendar will just display whatever events you give it.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.Yes the user will stored in session.I will study more on the database relationship to solve this.